Why are kernels often singular on the diagonal?
Many kernels/integral operators are given in terms of a function that is singular near the origin:

For example, the heat kernel on $\mathbb{R}^d$:
$$
\operatorname{K}\left(t,x,y\right) =
\frac{1}{\left(\, 4\pi t\,\right)^{d/2}}\,
\exp\left(-\,{\left\vert\left\vert\, x - y\,\right\vert\right\vert^{2} \over 4t}\right)
$$
is singular when $x = y$.

Is there any deep or conceptual reason why such kernels or fundamental solutions are often singular on the diagonal?

What do you mean by this kernel being singular at $x=y$? It is well-defined everywhere except for $t\leq0$

The most well known example of an integral transform with singular kernel is the Hilbert transform. Outside of solving some PDEs (or approximate solutions), most people working on integral transforms work with non singular kernels. Singular kernels make the analysis very tricky and much less amenable to soft analysis techniques and require a lot more hard analysis.

Indeed, singular integral operators are an entire subfield. These specific operators are well studied https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_integral_operators_of_convolution_type

A partial answer is that many kernels of interest are Green's functions of some PDE, and if that PDE is translation invariant, then the Green's function will be of the form $G(x,y) = \Phi(x-y)$ and hence it will have this diagonal structure you mention. Many systems of interest are translation invariant, so it shows up a lot. Your kernel also has this structure as a function on $\mathbb{R}^4$, where it would have inputs $(t,s,x,y)$, it's just that we consider the unit impulse always to be at the initial time $0$, so we have $s=0$ in this kernel and hence have a singularity when $s=t=0$.
As for why the function is singular, it is because its derivatives do not exist at the origin by definition since they are the solutions to $LG(x,y) = \delta(x-y)$ for some differential operator $L$. Depending on the order of the differential operator and the dimension of the underlying space, the singularity can be stronger or weaker. Take for example the Green's function of the Laplacian in $\mathbb{R}^n$. When $n=1$, the Green's function is continuous with a singularity in the first derivative and in higher dimensions the Green's function has a genuine singularity at the origin of increasing order with $n$.

Thank you. The example I had in mind was the fundamental solution for the Laplacian, but for some reason I wrote down the heat kernel! So the singularity always arises from the fact that the kernel $G$ satisfies $LG(x,y) = \delta(x-y)$?

Yes. The exact nature of the singularity depends on the operator.

And I assume the reason such operators often increase the regularity of the function it acts on is precisely because $G$ is a solution to the differential operator $L$?

Yes. The operator associated with convolution with these Green’s functions can be viewed as an inverse of $L$ over some domain of sufficiently regular functions.

Thanks for all the help!
